# Trouble with regex for Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, sinatra

I'm trying to make a regular expression for a route. It's supposed to admit routes like:

```
/prov/17/dist/24/agregarDepartamento
/lista/agregarDepartamento
/prov/20/agregarDepartamento
```

This is my ruby code:

```
get ([prov/...]*[dist/...]*agregarDepartamento+) do
   #process
end
```

but it's not working. How can I do this?

Comment: [http://rubular.com] This is a great tool for regex.

Comment: @JackMoody I'm sorry but I've tried with it and I don't understand it

Comment: No problem Diana. Just trying to give you an option. Looks like you got a good answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this one Diana?

```
prov_paths = [
  '/prov/:prov_id/dist/:dist_id/agregarDepartamento',
  '/lista/agregarDepartamento',
  '/prov/:prov_id/agregarDepartamento'
]
prov_paths.each do |prov_path|
  get prov_path do
    # process
  end
end
```

Comment: My pleasure ^_^